# Javascript, pausing a typewriter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question with my javascript. The problem I am facing is that, with my one page website. I have a typewriter.js that is running within a div. What I am trying to accomplish is that when you are scrolling up or down, the typewriter 'freezes' (pause) and when you scroll back to the page, the typewriter continues again.

**HTML Typewriter**

```
    <div class="type-o">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut pellentesque consectetur pulvinar. Pellentesque a dapibus nisi.</p>
    </div>
```

**Javascript onepage**

```
//section 1
if(anchorLink == 'Illusiveman'){
    $(".type-o").typewriter('typestart');
}

if ((index == 2 && direction == 'down') || (index == 2 && direction == 'up')){
    $(".type-o").typewriter('typepause');
}
```

**Javascript Typewriter**

```
    $.fn.typewriter = function(a) {
        this.each(function() {
            var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.text(), progress = 0;
            $ele.text('');
            var timer = setInterval(function() {

                if(a = 'typestart'){
                    $ele.text(str.substring(0, progress++) + (progress & 1 ? '_' : ''));
                    if (progress >= str.length) clearInterval(timer);

                }else if(a == 'typepause'){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }   

            }, 100);
        });     
    return this;
};
```

What I am having now, is that if you leave the content.. The typewriter continues, but when you scroll back to the content, the typewriter starts again, like when you are having insert enabled in word. And I am currently out of idea's, so that is why I need some help.

- By the way, I am using [Jason Frame's Grab Bag](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/text-effects.html) typewriter script here.
- **I created a live-preview of my problem.8 The button should be ofcourse be the scroll function. http://jsbin.com/eguxev/134/edit?html,js,output**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**
after correcting your code([see](http://jsfiddle.net/43tFE/2/) for your self ) you only have to bind the scroll event to the whatever element you want and the scrolling will pause the type

```
$( "yourelemntselector" ).scroll(function(){
    $(".type-o").typewriter('typepause');
});
```

Comment: I created a live-preview of my problem. The button should be ofcourse be the scroll function. http://jsbin.com/eguxev/134/edit?html,js,output

Comment: the pause button doesnt work wich propably means your function to pause the type doesnt work

Comment: the problem is that the 'typestart' function keeps running, even after the 'typepause'..

Comment: You are a GOD! Youness, the only problem is that when I call in 'typestart' after the 'typepause' the script does not continue with the rest of the text after the character that paused.. (See RUN button -> http://jsfiddle.net/vYX2R/)

Comment: hi sorry i was not here i will see and get back to you

Comment: Like I said, you are a GOD. Thanks so much!